# Vanilla JS to dynamically add or remove div boxes

Tags: javascript

When checking on the checkbox i'm trying to create the div boxes and when unchecking remove it dynamically.

I know with React i could do this in 2min but i'm trying to learn Vanilla JS way

Current issues i'm having:

1. When checking on checkbox it renders more elements than one
2. When unchecking checkbox for example all one element is still rendered.

END GOAL: dynamically add and remove Div boxes depending on what is in `state` variable, (`console.log` that its outputting should give guidance on how correctly it should look) but also making sure no extra boxes are being used / rendered.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')
  let state = []

  for (idx of checkbox) {
    idx.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      if (e.currentTarget.checked === true) {
        state.push(e.currentTarget.id)
        renderOnDom(state, 'add', e.currentTarget.id) // Experimenting
      }
      if (e.currentTarget.checked === false) {
        state = state.filter((item) => item !== e.currentTarget.id)
        renderOnDom(state, 'remove', e.currentTarget.id) // Experimenting
      }
      console.log('state', state)
    })
  }
}

const renderOnDom = (el, option, id) => {
  if (option === 'add') {
    el.map((item, idx) => {
      const div = document.createElement('div')
      div.setAttribute('key', item)
      div.className = 'test'
      div.innerHTML = `Box ${item}`
      document.querySelector('#projects').appendChild(div)
    })
  }

  if (option === 'remove') {
    const test = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
    const prod = document.querySelector('#projects')
    for (const iterator of test) {
      if (iterator.attributes.key.value === id) {
        prod.removeChild(prod.firstChild)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" data="name1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="id1">Test 1</label>

      <input id="id2" data="name2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="id2">Test 2</label>

      <input id="id3" data="name3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="id3">Test 3</label>

      <div id="projects"></div>
```

Comment: _"When checking on checkbox it renders more elements than one"_ - Because you add every element in `state`

Comment: ? my state which is `console.log` it showing it correctly. So if there is 3 elements in the state it needs to render those 3, but not duplicate them when rendering

Comment: `el` is the "state", `el.map()` (which is btw the wrong tool, check its documentation) iterates over all elements in `el` and adds every element in `el`/"state" to the DOM (`.createElement()`, `.appendChild()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have updated your snippet to do what I think you want to do.

In a nutshell, the source of truth is `state` array. So after any changes to it, reset the dom using `resetDom()` and then fire `renderOnDom()`.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')
  let state = []

  for (idx of checkbox) {
    idx.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      if (e.currentTarget.checked === true) {
        state.push(e.currentTarget.id)
      }
      if (e.currentTarget.checked === false) {
        state = state.filter((item) => item !== e.currentTarget.id)
      }
      renderOnDom(state, e.currentTarget.id)
    })
  }
}
const resetDom = () => {
  const projects = document.querySelector("#projects");
  while (projects.firstChild) {
    projects.removeChild(projects.firstChild)
  }
}
const renderOnDom = (el, id) => {
  resetDom();
  el.forEach((item, idx) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.setAttribute('key', item)
    div.className = 'test'
    div.innerHTML = `Box ${item}`
    document.querySelector('#projects').appendChild(div)
  })

}
```

```html
<input id="id1" data="name1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="id1">Test 1</label>

<input id="id2" data="name2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="id2">Test 2</label>

<input id="id3" data="name3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="id3">Test 3</label>

<div id="projects"></div>
```

Comment: Dude you are amazing

Comment: Thanks @Marius :D and Andreas  - yes since we are not returning anything, forEach makes more sense !!.

Comment: thanks Andreas i'm so used to React using map constantly